# where does printf's output go in php code?

Tags: php, path, logging

This is my first time working on php code.
I've put some printf code in it and wonder where the output goes?

Thank you

- edit

I'd like to debug this php code.
Don't know if there's a debugger for php but I can print a log.

How should I print a log then?

Comment: +1 becuse this question is extremly funny xDD

Comment: it wasn't *that* funny. Where was the research effort?

Comment: haha glad to know made you laugh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes into the HTTP stream or the output buffer.

Answer (score 4):

That would be the HTML output of your php script; or the command line if you are you are using php command line parser (php-cli).